# Page not found (404) on django

Tags: django, django-views

I am using django 3.2 to build a personal e-commerce project, Got Error-Page not found (404) on visiting my products page url Method:GET URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/products Using the URLconf defined in main.urls. I have followed all the conventions and the other pages are all working but this one is giving me a[urls[\views][1][browser display] hard time as i feel everything is correct, i might be wrong, pls help and if u need to see more of my code, please let me know.

This is my code for urls

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic import *
from main import models, views
 
app_name = 'main'
 
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('about_us/', views.about_us, name='about_us'),
    path('contact-us/', views.ContactUsView.as_view(), name='contact_us'),
    path(
        "products/<slug:tag>/",
        views.ProductListView.as_view(),
        name="products"
        ),
    path("product/<slug:slug>/", DetailView.as_view(model=models.Product), name='product'),
]
```

my code for views

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from main import models

class ProductListView(ListView):
    template_name = "main/product_list.html"
    paginate_by = 4

    def get_queryset(self):
        tag = self.kwargs['tag']
        self.tag = None
        if tag != "all":
            self.tag = get_object_or_404(
                models.ProductTag, slug=tag 
            )
        if self.tag:
            products = models.Product.objects.active().filter(
                tags=self.tag 
            )
        else:
            products = models.Product.objects.active()

        return products.order_by("name")
```

then my browser

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/products
Using the URLconf defined in booktime.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='home']
about_us/ [name='about_us']
contact-us/ [name='contact_us']
products/<slug:tag>/ [name='products']
product/<slug:slug>/ [name='product']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, products, didn’t match any of these.
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a url-path for /products/.  Your project always expects a tag to be passed on.  You might want to add list view specifically for this purpose rather then using 'None'

Comment: i am new to programming, could u kindly show what u r saying with a code, i'd appreciate that and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a path to url ending with "products/". You create url just to sent with parameter "tags". "products/slug:tag/"

So, add 'products/' to your urls path the url below and you'll access with 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/'

path(
"products/",
views.ProductListView.as_view(),
name="products"
)

Comment: @patrick-idungafa , worked? If no, please, let me know, maybe I can help you another way.

Comment: Perfect! If you mark this answer as accepted, will be more magical! Best Regards!